# some pages of my web application required login,i am trying to share such pages on fb, twitter etc. then sharing preview showing login page preview?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, codeigniter

some pages of my web application required login, when i trying to share such pages on facebook, twitter etc. then sharing preview showing login page preview??

my code snippet:

```
.....
.....

<li>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?p[url]=<?php echo $page_url_to_share; ?>" target="_blank">
             <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
</li>
<li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $page_url_to_share; ?>" target="_blank">
             <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
</li>

.....
.....
```

If page requires web application login then how can i show proper preview of such pages? I also applied same SEO information on login page from which its get redirected. Though its not showing proper preview?

**please give me idea to show proper sharing preview of login required pages** (I have fb, twitter etc. sharing buttons)

Comment: does your pages have `open graph meta tags`?? if they are present in your page then fb will read those tags and will generate the preview accordingly, read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Comment: I also applied same SEO information on login page from which its get redirected. Though its not showing proper preview?

Comment: also tried facebook share debugger, but not happening

Comment: You will need to implement an exemption to your automatic redirect for the Facebook scraper (can be recognized by its user agent), and present it with the appropriate meta data under the originally requested URL. Be aware of course that whoever fakes such a user agent, would get to see the same content - so take into account what info you might need to keep private.

Comment: Whether sharing login-protected stuff makes that much sense in the first place, different question … maybe for closed groups where most people are members of your site or something. For regular users it might be a rather frustrating experience to follow links from Facebook, only to be then told they would need to create an account on an external site first to see anything meaningful …

Comment: Is the login error is shown on the same page or it gets redirected on the login page if user isnt logged in?? 1) if the error is displayed on the same page then  do print your open graph tags before the error gets printed 2) if it gets redirected to login page then do check the last page using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable, and print the particular opengraph tags on the login page...

Comment: i want to show that kind of pages only registered clients only.. if registered client goes to share such pages on social media then there should be proper preview of that page. Anyone click on shared link then it will get redirected to login page

Comment: Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], I also applied same meta tags of such pages to login page from which its get redirected.. but though not done